# What is the general term for sentient beings in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

'Humanoid' is too-specific a term for beings in the Star Wars universe, since many, such as Jabba the Hutt or R2-D2, don't have humanoid body plans.

Is there a general term for conscious beings in Star Wars?

Comment: I believe it's just "sentient beings". Clearly, it has been used extensively in Legends and indeed is the default term used in modern science fiction for, in my own words, "beings intelligent enough to form civilisations". The official English dictionary definitions for sentience don't quite imply that - or at least I'm still grappling with it - but that's what virtually every science fiction publication call "aliens"

Comment: @thegreatjedi: IIRC, the word was first used in the context of philosophy and had quite a different meaning than that common in science fiction.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I guess it's complicated in reality, since in order to correctly define a word to describe what we today call "sentients", we first need to satisfactorily answer the question "What makes us human". After all, we are the only real world "sentients" we know of. The term sentient has probably been appropriated by some science fiction writer in the past for lack of a better word.

Comment: @thegreatjedi: actually the dictionary definition [includes animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentience#Animal_welfare.2C_rights.2C_and_sentience).  The science fiction usage may have occurred because it was confused with [sapience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom#Sapience) or it may have been a deliberate rejection of the philosophical distinction.  (Note that I'm not objecting to your usage, just trying to explain why it doesn't gibe with what the dictionary says.)

Comment: FWIW I was borrowing the term from Buddhism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentient_beings_%28Buddhism%29 "In Buddhism, sentient beings are beings with consciousness, sentience, or in some contexts life itself.[1] Sentient beings are composed of the five aggregates, or skandhas: matter, sensation, perception, mental formations and consciousness."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term "***Sentients***" is used in a wide range of Disney-Canon material including within the Star Wars databank, various novelisations and in the Star Wars: Rebels TV series.

---

From the SW Databank article on [The Chadra-Fan](http://www.starwars.com/databank/chadra-fan)

> *Chadra-Fan are meter-high, rodent-like sentients with big ears and
>   dark eyes ...*

and [the Gotal](http://www.starwars.com/databank/gotal)

> *Horned sentients with furred faces, Gotals were native to Antar IV but
>   lived on many planets in the galaxy, from Coruscant to Tatooine and
>   Lothal ...*

and from the [SW: The Phantom Menace Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel))

> *Not since whatever elder race had built and once occupied the Sacred
>   Place had it played host to as many sentients and droids. Not merely
>   the Gungans from Otoh Gunga and other bubble cities, and Amidala, her
>   retinue, and the Jedi, but also OOM-9’s squadrons of STAPs, searching
>   in all the wrong places, and the droid commander’s long-range
>   reconnaissance platoons of battle droids, many of which had become
>   mired in the soft ground.*

and from the [SW: Attack of the Clones novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel))

> *He slipped in silently and moved from shadow to shadow, then ducked behind a wind curtain as he heard the approach of a pair of strange-looking creatures-Geonosians, he supposed. They wore little clothing, and their skin was reddish, like the air about them, with flaps hanging in rolls in many places about their slender frames. Leathery wings showed behind their bony shoulders. Their heads were large and elongated, their skulls ridged top and side, and they had thick-lidded, bulbous eyes. Their expressions seemed to be locked in a perpetual scowl. “Too many sentients,” he heard one of them say. “It is not your place to question Archduke Poggle the Lesser,” the other scolded, and grumbling, the pair wandered away.*

and from Star Wars: Rebels - '[Droids in Distress](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Droids_in_Distress)'

> **RX-24:** *"Sentients, please prepare for takeoff."*